# Shell script to automate SFTP Upload?

Tags: sftp

I've been trying to get a PHP script to SFTP upload a file, but failed.  I tried asking my question on stackoverflow.com but haven't received a working solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767117/how-to-sftp-upload-files-from-php

So now I want to try a different approach.  Is there a way to write a shell script that can issue several commands to sftp upload a file to another server?  If I were to issue commands one by one from terminal, it would look like:

```
>sftp user@server.com
>password: mypassword
>put file.csv
```

I tried putting these three lines into a ./automaticupload file.  When I executed the file, but the terminal shows me:

```
user@server.com's password:
```

even though I typed in the password line in automaticupload.

I am unable to create  a passwordless ssh/scp/sftp account.  The remote server.com does not give me ssh or scp access.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use sftp from a script you need to [setup passwordless SSH keys with ssh-keygen(1)](https://serverfault.com/questions/2429/how-do-you-setup-ssh-to-authenticate-using-keys-instead-of-a-username-password)  or use [sshpass](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/)

My vote would nearly always be for the former, but it can depend on the situation which is more appropiate.

Comment: I don't have privileges to set up either of those options.  The remote server belongs to a company that deals with financial transactions, so they're limiting my access to only sftp uploads.

Comment: and forcing me to supply username and password each time

Comment: so you've tried uploading your public key in the appropriate place with the correct permissions and it ignored them?

Comment: yeah, it says permission denied when i try to enter the .ssh directory

Answer (score 1):

Install and use expect, it's designed for exactly this kind of situation.

Use the autoexpect script to generate an expect script from a recorded live session. Depending on the distribution, autoexpect is either included in the main expect package, or (strangely) in expect-dev on Ubuntu.

Comment: does expect stores the password encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

Use socat: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

For example:

`(sleep 2; echo password) | socat - EXEC: "sftp -o batchmode=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -b batchfile user@host",pty,setsid,ctty`