# SSH authentication working unless ran from script?

Tags: ssh, authentication, scripting, password

I have set up my server to allow key/pair authentication by following instructions similar to what is found in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/2429/how-do-you-setup-ssh-to-authenticate-using-keys-instead-of-a-username-password).

As far as I can tell that is working correctly. If I do the following, for example, it works correctly:

```
ssh myusername@mydomain.com
```

It will NOT prompt me for a password. This is what I want to happen. However if I write a small bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
ssh myusername@mydomain.com
```

and execute with:

```
sudo ./mytestscript.sh
```

...it will prompt me with:

```
myusername@mydomain.com's password:
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to login from within my script without being prompted for a password!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that the script works fine if you run it without `sudo`.  If that is the case, than your problem is that ssh is now looking for the public key in root's home directory instead of yours.  Add a `-i` option to your ssh command specifying the path to the key you've configured, or use root's public key instead.

If you're using `ssh-agent` to store a decrypted version of your key rather than using a passphrase-less key, you also need to edit `/etc/sudoers` and add `env_keep+="SSH_AUTH_SOCK SVN_SSH` to the `Defaults` so ssh can find your auth socket.

Comment: You are correct! The script does work without using sudo. I will try the -i option and let you know the result! Thanks!

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks again! I would vote you up but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: Heh... You should be able to mark an answer as "accepted" even with low reputation points.  Glad it worked!